# How do I get the jquery cycle carousel to set the active class correctly in the first round of slides?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, carousel, cycle

I'm trying to use a cycle carousel to have a carousel slideshow. The idea is that I have Screenshots from a mobile App and those screenshots get pushed into an image of a phone. The Screenshots currently not inside the phone image should have an overlay to make them less visible.

So far I have found the solution for everything I need except something I assume is a bug in the carousel plugin.

I need the active class so I can remove an overlay the other slides do have, but in the first cycle of the slides the active class is set to the wrong (not visible) element.

I assume this is because the carousel plugin adds multiple versions of the same slide. (I think it's slides*4), but I don't know how to get around it or fix it. These are the 2 lines that remove every active class from those x4 slides and tries to add the class to the currently actually active slide.

```js
wrap.find('.cycle-slide-active').removeClass('cycle-slide-active');
opts.slides.eq(opts.startingSlide).addClass('cycle-slide-active');
```

This is the HTML Markup it creates. The actually visible slide is 8 Elements (a full set of slides) before the one marked active.

```
<div id="mobileslideshow" class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-fx="carousel" data-cycle-timeout="10000" data-cycle-visible="1" data-cycle-slides="> div" data-cycle-starting-slide="0" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;"><div class="cycle-slide cycle-sentinel" style="position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 100; opacity: 1; display: block; visibility: hidden;">
        <img src="/Web/Content/Images/MobileSlideshow/phonescreen01.jpg" alt="" style="visibility: hidden;">
        <div class="slideshow_overlay" style="visibility: hidden;"></div>
    </div><div class="cycle-carousel-wrap" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; top: 0px; left: -2504px; position: absolute; white-space: nowrap;"><div class="cycle-slide" style="position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 100; opacity: 1; display: inline-block; visibility: visible;">
        <img src="/Web/Content/Images/MobileSlideshow/phonescreen01.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="slideshow_overlay"></div>
    </div><div class="cycle-slide" style="position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 99; display: inline-block;">
        <img src="/Web/Content/Images/MobileSlideshow/phonescreen02.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="slideshow_overlay"></div>
    </div><div class="cycle-slide" style="position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 97; display: inline-block;">
        <img src="/Web/Content/Images/MobileSlideshow/phonescreen03.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="slideshow_overlay"></div>
    </div><div class="cycle-slide" style="position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 96; display: inline-block;">
        <img src="/Web/Content/Images/MobileSlideshow/phonescreen04.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="slideshow_overlay"></div>
    </div><div class="cycle-slide" style="position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 95; display: inline-block;">
        <img src="/Web/Content/Images/MobileSlideshow/phonescreen05.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="slideshow_overlay"></div>
    </div><div class="cycle-slide" style="position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 94; display: inline-block;">
        <img src="/Web/Content/Images/MobileSlideshow/phonescreen06.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="slideshow_overlay"></div>
    </div><div class="cycle-slide" style="position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 93; display: inline-block;">
        <img src="/Web/Content/Images/MobileSlideshow/phonescreen07.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="slideshow_overlay"></div>
    </div><div class="cycle-slide" style="position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 92; display: inline-block;">
        <img src="/Web/Content/Images/MobileSlideshow/phonescreen08.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="slideshow_overlay"></div>
    </div><div class="cycle-slide" style="position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 100; opacity: 1; display: inline-block; visibility: visible;">
        <img src="/Web/Content/Images/MobileSlideshow/phonescreen01.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="slideshow_overlay"></div>
    </div><div class="cycle-slide" style="position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 99; display: inline-block;">
        <img src="/Web/Content/Images/MobileSlideshow/phonescreen02.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="slideshow_overlay"></div>
    </div><div class="cycle-slide" style="position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 97; display: inline-block;">
        <img src="/Web/Content/Images/MobileSlideshow/phonescreen03.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="slideshow_overlay"></div>
    </div><div class="cycle-slide" style="position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 96; display: inline-block;">
        <img src="/Web/Content/Images/MobileSlideshow/phonescreen04.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="slideshow_overlay"></div>
    </div><div class="cycle-slide" style="position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 95; display: inline-block;">
        <img src="/Web/Content/Images/MobileSlideshow/phonescreen05.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="slideshow_overlay"></div>
    </div><div class="cycle-slide" style="position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 94; display: inline-block;">
        <img src="/Web/Content/Images/MobileSlideshow/phonescreen06.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="slideshow_overlay"></div>
    </div><div class="cycle-slide" style="position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 93; display: inline-block;">
        <img src="/Web/Content/Images/MobileSlideshow/phonescreen07.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="slideshow_overlay"></div>
    </div><div class="cycle-slide" style="position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 92; display: inline-block;">
        <img src="/Web/Content/Images/MobileSlideshow/phonescreen08.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="slideshow_overlay"></div>
    </div><div class="cycle-slide cycle-slide-active" style="position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 100; opacity: 1; display: inline-block; visibility: visible;">
        <img src="/Web/Content/Images/MobileSlideshow/phonescreen01.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="slideshow_overlay"></div>
    </div><div class="cycle-slide" style="position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 99; display: inline-block;">
        <img src="/Web/Content/Images/MobileSlideshow/phonescreen02.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="slideshow_overlay"></div>
    </div><div class="cycle-slide" style="position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 97; display: inline-block;">
        <img src="/Web/Content/Images/MobileSlideshow/phonescreen03.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="slideshow_overlay"></div>
    </div><div class="cycle-slide" style="position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 96; display: inline-block;">
        <img src="/Web/Content/Images/MobileSlideshow/phonescreen04.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="slideshow_overlay"></div>
    </div><div class="cycle-slide" style="position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 95; display: inline-block;">
        <img src="/Web/Content/Images/MobileSlideshow/phonescreen05.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="slideshow_overlay"></div>
    </div><div class="cycle-slide" style="position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 94; display: inline-block;">
        <img src="/Web/Content/Images/MobileSlideshow/phonescreen06.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="slideshow_overlay"></div>
    </div><div class="cycle-slide" style="position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 93; display: inline-block;">
        <img src="/Web/Content/Images/MobileSlideshow/phonescreen07.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="slideshow_overlay"></div>
    </div><div class="cycle-slide" style="position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 92; display: inline-block;">
        <img src="/Web/Content/Images/MobileSlideshow/phonescreen08.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="slideshow_overlay"></div>
    </div><div class="cycle-slide" style="position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 100; opacity: 1; display: inline-block; visibility: visible;">
        <img src="/Web/Content/Images/MobileSlideshow/phonescreen01.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="slideshow_overlay"></div>
    </div><div class="cycle-slide" style="position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 99; display: inline-block;">
        <img src="/Web/Content/Images/MobileSlideshow/phonescreen02.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="slideshow_overlay"></div>
    </div><div class="cycle-slide" style="position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 97; display: inline-block;">
        <img src="/Web/Content/Images/MobileSlideshow/phonescreen03.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="slideshow_overlay"></div>
    </div><div class="cycle-slide" style="position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 96; display: inline-block;">
        <img src="/Web/Content/Images/MobileSlideshow/phonescreen04.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="slideshow_overlay"></div>
    </div><div class="cycle-slide" style="position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 95; display: inline-block;">
        <img src="/Web/Content/Images/MobileSlideshow/phonescreen05.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="slideshow_overlay"></div>
    </div><div class="cycle-slide" style="position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 94; display: inline-block;">
        <img src="/Web/Content/Images/MobileSlideshow/phonescreen06.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="slideshow_overlay"></div>
    </div><div class="cycle-slide" style="position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 93; display: inline-block;">
        <img src="/Web/Content/Images/MobileSlideshow/phonescreen07.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="slideshow_overlay"></div>
    </div><div class="cycle-slide" style="position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 92; display: inline-block;">
        <img src="/Web/Content/Images/MobileSlideshow/phonescreen08.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="slideshow_overlay"></div>
    </div><div class="cycle-slide" style="position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 100; opacity: 1; display: inline-block; visibility: visible;">
        <img src="/Web/Content/Images/MobileSlideshow/phonescreen01.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="slideshow_overlay"></div>
    </div><div class="cycle-slide" style="position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 99; display: inline-block;">
        <img src="/Web/Content/Images/MobileSlideshow/phonescreen02.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="slideshow_overlay"></div>
    </div><div class="cycle-slide" style="position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 97; display: inline-block;">
        <img src="/Web/Content/Images/MobileSlideshow/phonescreen03.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="slideshow_overlay"></div>
    </div><div class="cycle-slide" style="position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 96; display: inline-block;">
        <img src="/Web/Content/Images/MobileSlideshow/phonescreen04.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="slideshow_overlay"></div>
    </div><div class="cycle-slide" style="position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 95; display: inline-block;">
        <img src="/Web/Content/Images/MobileSlideshow/phonescreen05.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="slideshow_overlay"></div>
    </div><div class="cycle-slide" style="position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 94; display: inline-block;">
        <img src="/Web/Content/Images/MobileSlideshow/phonescreen06.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="slideshow_overlay"></div>
    </div><div class="cycle-slide" style="position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 93; display: inline-block;">
        <img src="/Web/Content/Images/MobileSlideshow/phonescreen07.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="slideshow_overlay"></div>
    </div><div class="cycle-slide" style="position: static; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 92; display: inline-block;">
        <img src="/Web/Content/Images/MobileSlideshow/phonescreen08.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="slideshow_overlay"></div>
    </div></div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions how to fix that?

Comment: Have you tried using just the [Bootstrap Carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel) instead? I think it would solve your problem and make you also write less stuff.

Comment: have not, but since I already use the cycle plugin on other pages I'd like to  use that instead of loading another plugin for every slightly different use case. The cycle plugin seems the most flexible of those and It would be perfect if it works correctly.
Also - how does it make me write less stuff? In the cycle plugin I have a container div, give this the correct class and have all the options as html attributes and in the container I simply write the HTML of the slides. I don't write a single line of JS. How CAN you even reduce that?